# Iterated cross sum in C

Tags: c

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

> Now write a program to calculate the iterated cross sum. This is calculated by iterating the cross sum until you arrive at a single digit number. Example:
> 4391873 -> 35 -> 8.

> Note: You need nested loops and for understanding what a corss sum does suppose you have the number 14 then its cross sum is 5 = 1+4. Another word may be horizontal checksum.

I have the following code for this, which also calculates simple cross sums, but it doesn't work with the example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
    {   
    
    int n = 0;
    int c = 0;
    printf("please give us your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
   while((c==0) || (c>10)){
    
        while ((n != 0) || (c>10)) {

            if (n % 10 != 0) {

                c = c + n % 10;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            else {
                n = n / 10;
            }

        }
        
   }
    
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
   
}
```

I had thought about linking two while loops, but I can't get it right to calculate the cross sum of the cross sum here. Do you have a tip for this?

Edit: I posted the code.

Comment: Please don't share code as images.

Comment: "Cross sum" is used in mathematical puzzles, you may want to define it as you use it here.

Comment: Suppose you have the number 14 then its cross sum is 5 = 1+4. Another word may be horizontal checksum.

Comment: If `c` is greater than 10, when does your code ever reduce it to something smaller? Forget about C code for the moment. Write down a series of simple steps that would calculate the cross sum of a numeral. Get the simple steps write, then think about writing a program for them.

Comment: That is the basic problem I need help with. I don't know how to use c again to form its cross sum since c has at the end of the inner while loop a given value that needs to be treated as n was at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {

    int sum=0, dsum=0, mod=0,n;
    printf("please give us your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nCross sum: %d",n);
   while(n>10)
    {
            mod= n%10;
            sum=sum+mod;
            n=n/10;
            if (n<10)
                {
                    sum=sum+n;
                    n=sum;
                    dsum=sum;
                    printf(" -> %d", dsum);
                    sum=0;
                }
    }
    if(dsum==0)
    {
        printf("-> %d", n);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you all, your comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration of the outer loop you need to assign C to N and 0 to C.
The following solution uses the Ada language.

```ada
-- Now write a program to calculate the iterated cross sum.
-- This is calculated by iterating the cross sum until you arrive
-- at a single digit number. Example: 4391873 -> 35 -> 8.
-- Note: You need nested loops.

with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Num  : Natural;
   Temp : Natural;
   Sum  : Natural := 0;
begin
   Put ("Enter an positive integer: ");
   Get (Num);
   Temp := Num;
   loop
      while Temp > 0 loop
         Sum  := Sum + (Temp rem 10);
         Temp := Temp / 10;
      end loop;
      exit when Sum < 10;
      Temp := Sum;
      Sum  := 0;
   end loop;

   Put_Line ("Original number:" & Num'Image & "  cross sum:" & Sum'Image);
end Main;
```

You  will have to rethink your outer loop termination so that it works using C syntax. The Ada example exits the outer loop before assigning Sum to Temp and 0 to Sum.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a sentinel value of zero in:

```
while((c==0) || (c>10))
```

But if I enter `0`, this will enter an infinite loop. You want to calculate `c` from zero from `n`, *then* test if `c` is greater then 9. If it is, than you want to replace `n` by `c`. This is not one of the pre-pakaged loops in C, so you probably need `break` or `,`.

```
while ((n != 0) || (c>10))
```

The inner loop is just wrong. It should have no dependence on `c`; get rid of that `c>10`.

```
if (n % 10 != 0)
```

This is a redundant test; `0 % 10 == 0`, so this could be simplified.